# KEY `ix_deleted` (`deleted`) create table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
    `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` text,
    `content` text,
    `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `ix_deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT=1
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  COMMENT='Blog posts';
```

I have created table and i want to implement trigger. I want to know what is the purpose of this line of code in this query.

```
KEY `ix_deleted` (`deleted`)
```

Comment: It creates an index (or "key") on the `deleted` column. The index's identifier or name is `ix_deleted`. It's a common convention to prefix an index's name with `ix_` or `idx_`.

Comment: There are some details about this in the [`CREATE TABLE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) particluarly the `| {FULLTEXT|SPATIAL} [INDEX|KEY] [index_name] (index_col_name,...)` line.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You should include that as an answer